# AndEngine GLES1 and Tiled graphical glitches

Tags: android, andengine

I'm using AndEngine GLES1 and the program "Tiled" to create TMX tile maps to be used as levels and no matter what settings I use, I get the output image offset to the wrong image. I used several tutorials as well as the AndEngine TMX tutorial and I'm running into this problem no matter what I do. I copy and pasted the code several times checking for errors, so I know its not the code. Is there something special you have to do with "Tiled" to make TMX files for AndEngine GLES1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out what was going wrong. Your tileset image (the one that you are pulling tiles from to put on the map) must be have a resolution of a power of 2 (i.e. 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, etc...etc...) in both directions (width and height). Otherwise it won't work properly in android and AndEngine...